# how do I pass a range of numeric values in macro parameter?

Tags: macros, sas

I am trying to write a macro that display age from 20-40 or >=30 only when it is passed as a parameter.

The code looks like:

```
%macro detReport(p_age=);   

proc sql;

create table detail as

select acct_id,

   name format=$20. ,

   int(yrdif(Birthday,today(),'ACTUAL')) as Age,

   balance,

   state,

   last_Tran_date

   from profile

  %if &p_age ne "" %then %do;

        %if %index(&p_age,-) > 0 %then %do;

   where int(yrdif(Birthday,today(),'ACTUAL')) between (%scan(&p_age,1,"-") and 
   %scan(&p_age,2,"-"))

  %end;

   %end;

  %else %do;

   where (int(yrdif(Birthday,today(),'ACTUAL')) &p_age);

    %end;

  quit;

 proc print data =detail ;

 run;

 %mend detReport;

 %detReport( p_age =20-40)
```

The code works when a single value is passed (like >=30) but gives error when 20-40 is passed.

Any help is appreciated!

P.S A beginner here!

Comment: If you follow @Tom advice, the macro can also use the criteria parameter in a title or footnote. I.e. `footnote1 "age criteria: &p_age";`

Answer (score 2):

Why not just let the caller pass in the logic?

```
where (int(yrdif(Birthday,today(),'ACTUAL')) &p_age)
...
%detReport( p_age =between 20 and 40)
%detReport( p_age = >= 40)
```

Comment: I tried it but %detreport(p_age= between 20 and 40) giving an error . The single value is working

Comment: Did you make the change to how the macro is using the value of the parameter?